# How to switch between subdomain and namespace dynamically in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create a dynamic routes, like this

```
https://subdomain.mysite.me/admin
https://mysite.me/subdomain/admin
```

I can set my `routes` for `subdomain` constraints, or `namespace`, but I don't know how to make them both are available.

Answer (score 1):

You just check [this](https://railsforum.com/topic/1861-routes-custom-subdomains-and-adding-admin-namespace/)

I set up my rails app to use custom subdomains following this awesome RailsCast tutorial by Ryan Bates. Users can visit company.lvh.me:3000 and view all its relevant information. Now, I would like to add an admin subdomain on the front of the custom subdomain (admin.company.lvh.me:3000).

The idea is that I have specific admins for each blog with special controllers/views. So if admin is added to the front of the company subdomain, rails will route through the app/controllers/admin/blogs_controller.rb and show the app/views/admin/blogs/show.html.erb.

I've used the admin namespace and set it as a subdomain in some of my past Rails apps, but when I try that here I need the second subdomain to be dynamic:

```
namespace :admin, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin.DYNAMIC' } do
  match     '/',            to: 'blogs#show', via: 'get'
end
```

So if type admin.company in the subdomain constraint, it works like a charm, but how can make it dynamic? I've had no luck making it dynamic ('admin.' + Subdomain, etc.) in the routes files, which lead me to the thought: can I just use Ryan Bates's Subdomain class?

```
namespace :admin, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: Subdomain } do
  match '/', to: 'blogs#show', via: 'get'
end

class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end 
end

Relevant Routes
Prefix Verb  URI Pattern  Controller#action
 admin GET   /            admin/blogs#show
```